# No Design Preview shown when using Material Design

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design, androidx

I migrated my project to androidx and used the material design "getting startetd" guideline. However it seems that I am unable to get the design correctly rendered. The MainActivity is showing the following output:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component
>   requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).  at
>   com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:240)
>     at
>   com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:211)
>     at
>   com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:146)
>     at
>   com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:78)
>     at
>   com.google.android.material.internal.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.(ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java:58)
>     at
>   com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:115)
>     at
>   com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:111)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:401)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:184)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:142)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:229)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:421)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:432)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:336)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)  at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:327)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:386)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:450)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:590)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I can deploy it on the phone but the design preview just shows a white/blue empty screen with the errormessage from above. I am using SDK version 28, changed my styles.xml theme to 'materialcomponents' theme but nothing really helped.

Did I forget anything? I am wondering what component it is that requires AppCompat-Theme since android studio automatically converted everything to androidx and I don't have any AppCompat references.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
                layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
                app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You should add the layout that you're getting this error in.

Comment: @VedprakashWagh I added the layout

Comment: Are you using the latest material library?

Comment: Yes I am using the latest. The 1.1.0-alpha-07 version.

Comment: seems like it must be a bug from their part. I found an issue somewhat similar to your at https://github.com/oliexdev/openScale/issues/409